# Convert basic like function to ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have this very basic like function in my app but its not how i want it to be because every time i click the button it reloads the page, so i want to translate this codes to ajax request. but i dont know javascript or jquery.

in my Views.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('like', array('id' => $posts->id)) }}" class="like">Like</a><br>
```

and my routes

```
Route::get('like{id}', array(
            'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@like',
            'as' => 'like'
            ));
```

and my controller

```
public function like($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->likes++;
        $post->save();

        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

im hoping that someone can show me how this is done in ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
<a onclick="addLike()" class="like">Like</a><br>

<script>
    function addLike() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ URL::route('like', array('id' => $posts->id)) }}"
    })
}
</script>
```

You also have to include `jquery` to make this simple code work. See : [jQuery Get Started](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

If you think you will need more javascript in the near future, I advise you to put it in an external file and include it in your view. This helps keeping your html and javascript codes clear.

Comment: Actually it should, see [link](this http://jsfiddle.net/uucd9ehf/2/), when you click the like, it sends get requests to the url you were using before `{{ URL::route('like', array('id' => $posts->id)) }}` to add a like. I can suggest you to use Chrome Developer Tools to see what's going on. Maybe you haven't correctly imported jQuery ?